# Read XML children's value using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm reading an XML documents using ajax, how do I read the children's value?
This is how my XML format looks like:

```
<Music Title="Everything"> 
    <Artist Index="0" Format="FLAC">Zwei</Artist>
    <Artist Index="1" Format="MP3"/>
</Music>
```

And this is how I read the attribute using ajax

```
var loading = $.ajax({
    type:   "GET",
    url:    'stuff.xml',
    dataType: "xml"
});
loading.done(function(data) {
xmlDoc = $(data);
    var current = xmlDoc.find('Music[Name="Everything"] Artist[Index=0]');
    var append = current.attr('Format');  //=?
    //Read artist value
});
```

I wanted to read the artist value, which is Zwei, is there a built in function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the jQuery find() method, you can then use the text() function to retrieve the content of the text.  For example:

```
$(function() {
   var d = $.parseXML('<Music Title="Everything"><Artist Index="0" Format="FLAC">Zwei</Artist><Artist Index="1" Format="MP3"/></Music>');
   console.log("Here is the text: " + $(d).find("Music Artist").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you select the artists:

```
var current = $(xmlDoc).find("Artist");
```

Now `current` is populated as an array of all the artist. You can acces that array this way:

```
var append = current.eq(1).attr('Format'); //an output of this will display: MP3
```

Here is a FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/bb8whgj2/